# If more and more people will be diagnosed with depression, in what single stocks ought you invest?

Tags: stocks

Apologies if this question is unethical. Based on rises in suicidal ideation in [Canada](https://redd.it/bjqx5q), [US](https://redd.it/bbtqf4), [UK](https://redd.it/behbpq), I presuppose that increasingly many will be diagnosed with  anxiety, depression, and [suicidal ideation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicidal_ideation#Psychiatric_disorders).

1. How can an investor profit from the rise in psychiatric disorders? Invest in pharmaceuticals that manufacture medications for them like anti-depressants?
2. Any single stock recommendations?
3. I know about ETFs, but there isn't one just for mental health. Right?

Comment: Most pharmaceutical companies have very diverse portfolios. A larger demand for one single kind of drug might be insignificant compared to all the other market factors which affect their stock price.

Comment: Ethics aside, such a superficial observation about broad trends has absolutely no value for investment decisions. Investors deeply involved with companies with value exposure to such trends will not have failed to notice the same thing. Growth targets and forecasts will be substantially contingent on predictions about those trends. The general principle you're asking about will be thoroughly priced into the market.

Comment: @Will the smart money would be aware of these trends, but their analysis would incorporate the risk of their trend predictions being wrong. If Tamara is extremely confident in this trend's projection, then it is still a good investment. Also, you assume that because some informed investors might be aware of this trend that the market efficiently values these companies - not true.

Comment: @Blondie the set of people who can price the effects of fuzzy externalities like the rate of depression diagnoses more efficiently than the market at large and the set of people who need to solicit suggestions from the public as to which markets are most affected do not intersect.

Comment: @Will lol this made me laugh,very true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If more and more are getting diagnosed with depression or any other psychiatric disorders, pharma may not benefit. Psychiatrists may benefit. The cost of medicine is not much compare to doctors' hefty fees.

Networks of hospitals who are more focused on psychiatric problems will benefit. I don't think there such kind of hospitals in India which are listed on exchange.

This is just a straight answer to your questions. I am not supporting your idea of buying stocks which will benefit from psychiatric disorders.

Comment: Thanks. "pharma may not benefit" - why not? You're assuming that these patients won't be taking medications, right?

Comment: For psychiatric disorders, treatment involves therapy and care. 90% of the costs goes towards this sections. Medications costs little compare to these fees. Iam just telling my observations. Iam no expert in psychiatry.

Comment: Are you talking about US prices of medications ? People are sometimes spending hundreds of dollars every month on prescription medications (Also health insurance may be paying even more).